# Why did the Seq2SeqTrainer not stop when the EarlyStoppingCallback criteria is met?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, seq2seq, encoder-decoder

When trying to use EarlyStopping for Seq2SeqTrainer, e.g. patience was set to 1 and threshold 1.0:

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./',
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    logging_steps=1,
    save_steps=5,
    eval_steps=1,
    max_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    predict_with_generate=True,
    report_to=None,
    metric_for_best_model="chr_f_score",
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)

early_stop = EarlyStoppingCallback(2, 1.0)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=valid_data.with_format("torch"),
    eval_dataset=test_data.with_format("torch"),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    callbacks=[early_stop]
)

trainer.train()
```

The model continues training until `max_steps` instead of stopping after the stopping criteria is met.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or maybe some argument is missing in when I use Seq2SeqTrainer, a working code to replicate the issue can be found on https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/huggingface-earlystopping-callbacks?scriptVersionId=110637297

### Q: Why did the Seq2SeqTrainer not stop when the EarlyStoppingCallback criteria is met?

---

After the `max_steps`, if we do some probing, somehow the `early_stopping_patience_counter` has been reached but the training didn't stop

```
>>> early_stop.early_stopping_patience_counter
2
```

Comment: I may be mistaken...but the working code in your link...stops at iteration 7. exactly when patience of 2 ends with 1.0 deviation on chr_f_score. Are you certain the correct parameter is observed and its known that smaller is better or bigger is better? and isnt chr_f_score (bigger is better?) Default behaviour for earlystop is usually on loss. so smaller is better.

Comment: Ah it wasnt following my metric for best model but the generic validation loss. Is there a way to set the metric to stop on instead of the default loss?

Comment: According to the docs, setting metric_for_best_model should do it. I am not particularly sure how your data is set up, but if the name does not exist it will default to the loss. Try checking that your 'metric' is actually named properly.

Comment: Found the problem, it's because of the `save_state`, when it's set to 5 and the `eval_steps` is set to 1, then it'll need to reach 5 before the threshold + patience kicked in.

Comment: When I changed the `eval_steps` to be the same as pace as the `save_state` the early stopping works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments in the question, the unexpected behavior of `eval_steps` going beyond the early stopping is because of the `save_state` being set at 5.

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    ...,
    logging_steps=1,
    save_steps=5,
    eval_steps=1,
    max_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    metric_for_best_model="chr_f_score",
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)
```

To debug the `EarlyStoppingCallback`, try setting the `save_steps` to be the same as `eval_steps`, e.g.

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    ...,
    logging_steps=1,
    save_steps=1,
    eval_steps=1,
    max_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    metric_for_best_model="chr_f_score",
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)
```

Afterwards, you should see that the early stopping behavior is now expected to stop at the patience / threshold you've set.

Comment: I clarified it in the documentation of the EarlyStoppingCallback class. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the parameters of **EarlyStoppingCallback** as in the definition of the function in https://docs.fast.ai/callback.tracker.html

that is:

early_stop = EarlyStoppingCallback(min_delta=1.0, patience=2)